# If $\frac{f'}{f}=\frac{g'}{g}$ then $f=cg$ for some complex constant $c$

Tags: complex-analysis

Any ideas to solve the following problem

Suppose that $f$ and $g$ are two non vanishing holmorphic functions on a domain $D$. If $\frac{f'}{f}=\frac{g'}{g}$ then $f=cg$ for some constant $c\in D$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If

$\dfrac{f'}{f} = \dfrac{g'}{g} \tag{1}$

in $D$, then in $D$ we also have

$f'g - fg' = 0, \tag{2}$

and we may divide (2) through by $g^2 \ne 0$ to obtain

$\dfrac{f'g - fg'}{g^2} = 0. \tag{3}$

But, $fg^{-1}$ is well-defined in $D$ and

$(fg^{-1})' = f'g^{-1} - fg^{-2}g' = \dfrac{f'g - fg'}{g^2} = 0 \tag{4}$

in $D$ by (3); hence

$fg^{-1} = c \tag{5}$

in $D$ for some constant $c \in \Bbb C$.  But (5) is clearly equivalent to

$f = cg. \tag{6}$

***QED.***

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{f'}{f}=\frac{g'}{g} $$
so
$$\ln(f)=\ln(g)+constant$$
so
$$f=\exp(constant)\cdot g$$

Comment: But how do you know that $ln(f)$ is well defined?

Comment: It is more a physician way of thinking ;) I assume you can use the definition of the complex ln

Comment: @Robert Lewis. Your argument seems perflectly fine to me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @user153049:  yeah, I like it better than using (potentially) multi-valued logarithms, which I think might force us to choose $D$ simply connected.  Thanks for good words, and for the "acceptance".